# Oracle shows invalid character on constraint check

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

here is my code

```
Create table Member(
Member_Id Number(5) primary key,
Member_Name varchar2(30),
Member_address varchar2(50),
Acc_Open_Date Date,
Membership_type varchar2(20),
Fees_paid Number(4),
Max_Book_Allowed Number(2),
Penalty_Amount Number(7,2),
CONSTRAINT mt CHECK (Membership_type IN(‘Lifetime’,’Annual’,’Half Yearly’,’Quarterly’))
);
```

now i want to set the check constraint with some specific string and i use for comparing the IN but it shows again and again invalid character.

now by using alter table it works..

but my query is how can i use in create table statement.

Comment: Use `'` instead of `‘` character

Comment: no effect it also gives the same error message "invalid character"

Comment: did you replace both opening and closing quotes with correct character `'`?

Comment: yes ofcourse...

Comment: @VDeep - See my answer

Comment: You appear to have copied the create statement from some sort of Word processor that uses curved quote marks instead of apostrophes. Who knows what sort of other characters are lurking in there e.g. non-breaking spaces, tabs, hard carriage returns. If you use a simple text editor you won't need to post unhelpful non-technical questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

This works for me.

```
Create table Member(
Member_Id Number(5) primary key,
Member_Name varchar2(30),
Member_address varchar2(50),
Acc_Open_Date Date,
Membership_type varchar2(20),
Fees_paid Number(4),
Max_Book_Allowed Number(2),
Penalty_Amount Number(7,2),
CONSTRAINT mt CHECK (Membership_type IN('Lifetime','Annual','Half Yearly','Quarterly'))
)
```

Comment: yes yes i also tried..
actually I type all the code in m.s. word then paste into pl/sql that's the problem of word...
but after typing in notepad it runs...
thank you..

Comment: Do **NOT** use Word to edit SQL scripts. Use a plain text editor.